# Android: How to put image as Listview Header as in Twitter

Tags: android, listview

What is the recommended way to put a header on the android app like the twitter app (screenshot below - header marked).

I am extending ArrayAdapter to create the listing. But cannot find a way to put the header.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may take a look at the code of the android-actionbar project on GitHub: https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not part of the ListView. Headers scroll with the list, but Twitter's headers are fixed. You don't need to use a ListActivity to host a ListView, you can create a LinearLayout or whatever and have the ListView as part of it.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, that's not part of the listview. The google IO app uses the same kind of interface, and it's open source.

http://code.google.com/p/iosched/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `addHeaderView()` or `addFooterView()` on `ListView`

Comment: Or you can also have a separate view (may be linear or relative which has image inside it) as header and list view below the header.